# Notify a User if Exception happens not in Activity class

Tags: android

My `Activity` holds a member `member_one` which holds another member `member_two` which can throw an `Exception`. I need to show user a `Toast` if this `Exception` happens. In order to show a `Toast` I need to throw `Exception` from `member_tow` to `member_one` and then from `member_one` to my `Activity`. This approach leads to big changes and I don't want to do so. May be I just think wrong, is there any easy way to handle the exception?

Comment: pass `Context` to you `member_one`, `member_two`, and then use that `Context` make `Toast`.like `Toast.makeText(mContext, "Exception Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Is it a good practice to pass `Context` to such assistance classes?

Comment: Where you want to notify the `User` you must need a `Context`. As you see every `View` needs `Context`..Another solution would be : use `Interface` approach.

Comment: Please give an answer for `Interface` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I know there will be two solutions of the problem.

- pass `Context` to you `member_one`, `member_two` and then use that `Context` to make Toast. `Like Toast.makeText(mContext, "Exception Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Second approach will be through `Interface`

-Make a `Interface` method in your class of `member_one` and so on

like

```
public interface OnErrorOccured {
        public void whatIsErr(String msg);
    }

    OnErrorOccured onError;

    public void setOnDetailsLoadListener(OnErrorOccured onError) {
        this.onError = onError;
    }
`
```

and when ever you get`Exception` call `onError.whatIsErr(e.toString());`

and in main `Activity`

```
 member_one.setOnErrorListener(mErrorOccured);

 OnErrorOccured mErrorOccured =new OnErrorOccured() {

    @Override
    public void whatIsErr(String msg) {
        // Do what ever you want..show Toast, or do any UI update

    }
};
```

How other programmers know if they want to use one of these classes they need to set listeners?

Well for this you force the constructor to pass a listener.

Like

```
public yourConstructor(OnErrorOccured errorListener,.....)
{
   this.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
   ...

}
```

Comment: This `Interface` method does seem much cleaner (not passing a unneeded parameter) than my solution. I'll definitely start using this instead.

Comment: Is it safe to do so? How other programmers know if they want to use one of these classes they need to set listeners?

Comment: So finally this approach ia even more complex than passing a `Context`.

Comment: It is complex but it is a right approach to use it...If you want to show only a Toast then it is unnecessary. With interface method you can any thing like you can update `UI`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I've done (although I'm not sure if it's squeaky clean as I'm a novice developer) is pass the `Activity` as a parameter like so:

```
foo.bar(this, ...);
```

Then, I can catch the exception in the other method like so:

```
bar(final Activity activity, ...)
{
   try
   {
      // Whatever
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      Toast.makeText(activity, "You dun goofed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           .show();
   }
}
```

Again, I can't guarantee that this is safe practice and I would love to hear a better solution.